# Reading input Backslash

Tags: python, backslash

`binary = "\000\021\"\252\273\314"`. This is my input, and my function takes in this input and prints it out like so:

```
def do_print(string):
    print string

do_print(binary)
```

But this function prints out gibberish text. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the `repr` of the string?

```
def do_print(string):
    print(repr(string))

binary = "\000\021\"\252\273\314"
do_print(binary)
```

yields

```
'\x00\x11"\xaa\xbb\xcc'
```